# Android: Sliding Drawer Style Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am looking to animate a LinearLayout of mine.

I would like to make it move upward while looking like it is disappearing behind a line (View of height 1dp) above it, until it is finally completely gone. Then when I want to show it I would like to be able to reverse that.

I am kind of lost as to how to achieve this. My first thought was that I could maybe convert my Layout into a Clip-Drawable somehow and use a TranslateAnimation and change how much of it can be seen, but that seems overly complicated and difficult. How could I make an animation (maybe a set of animations?), or otherwise to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 1dp line is within a larger view, your LinearLayout can be animated to disappear behind it. Use TranslateAnimation with an animation listener, then in onAnimationEnd, you can set the visibility of your LinearLayout to View.GONE.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to get it to move behind the larger view? I seem to always have it go over my content above it using `new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-100);`

Comment: Sure, you need to call bringToFront() on your larger view so it's on top.